# Calculate 95% confidence interval on the mean

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I have an exercise that says

Find  a confidence interval of 95% on the mean number of games won by a team when x2=2300,x7=56 and x8=2100.

Is there a function in R that gives directly such confidence interval?

I've thought about using the function
`confint(f)`, but this function gives the result when it's about one or more parameters, and as far as I understand I don't have a parameter but a function like this beta0+beta1xi where the parameter beta is already estimated and the point xi would be x2,x7 and x8.

Another way would be to do it 'manually' but this complicates because I would have to calculate the standard error,the variance, the t value, etc.

Could you help please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the original data there were the vectors y,x2,x7,x8

Comment: I'm not seeing a clear statistical question here. You've given us 3 separate integers but you have not told us what they represent. What are x2, x7 and x8?

Comment: @42- x2 is passing yards, x7 is percent rushing and x8 is opponents' rushing yards. Those are data from National football league 1976 team performance (according to the book)

Comment: So it makes no sense to take the mean of x2,x7,and x8. Do you have vectors? Are there lengths for each of x2, x7,amd x8? Are these sums or summaries of  longer sets of values?

Comment: @42- Why makes no sense? To your questions, Yes, yes, not that I know.

Comment: Makes no sense to request a mean of three numbers that have such a tenuous relationship, and wouldn't even if they were measured in the same units, which they aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

There a function in R that gives directly such confidence interval.

Just type

```
predict.lm(f,newdata=data.frame(x2=2300,x7=56,x8=2100),interval="confidence")
```

Where `f` is the linear model, i.e. `f<-lm(y~x2+x7+x8)`

where `y,x2,x7,x8` are your particular vectors.

---

As a side note, note that this function can also give the "prediction" interval, just change "confidence" by "prediction".

Answer (score 2):

You need to look not at `confint` but [`predict.lm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.lm.html):

> **Details**
>
> `predict.lm` produces predicted values, obtained by evaluating the regression function in the frame newdata (which defaults to model.frame(object)). If the logical se.fit is TRUE, standard errors of the predictions are calculated. If the numeric argument scale is set (with optional df), it is used as the residual standard deviation in the computation of the standard errors, otherwise this is extracted from the model fit. Setting intervals specifies computation of confidence or prediction (tolerance) intervals at the specified level, sometimes referred to as narrow vs. wide intervals.`

You'll need to set up a data frame with the same column names as used in the model fit which contains the set values you want a prediction for, for the `newdata` argument.

Here's an example showing how to use `newdata`:

```
x1<-c(1,2,5,6); x2<-c(3,2,4,1); x3<-c(5,4,3,4); y<-c(21,21,27,23)
res<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3)
predict.lm(res,newdata=data.frame(x1=4,x2=4,x3=2),
            interval="confidence")
```

(i.e. you'll need something of the form `data.frame(x2= ..., x7=...` etc  but where you fill in the values you want)

However, you also need to tell it the type of interval you need.

(`predict` is the generic; if you call `predict` on an `lm` object, it will call `predict.lm`, but to get the right help you need to look directly at the specific function)

Comment: I don't understand very well. Could you explain with an example? What am I going to write in interval=" "?

Comment: It says type of interval calculation

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: The default (response) is what you need. Don't specify anything for it

Comment: Oh then why did you write: You'll need to set up a data frame with the same column names as used in the model fit which contains the set values you want a prediction for, for the newdata argument. ?

Comment: Because that's what you need for the `newdata` argument. Why would what you need for the `interval` argument (the default, so leave that blank) impact what you need for the `newdata` argument?

Comment: Would be predict(f), where f is the linear model (f<-y∼x2+x7+x8)?

Comment: No, I think would be predict(f,x2,x7,x8) where `newdata` is x2,x7,x8?

Comment: Comments  are not for extended discussion. You don't have a `newdata` argument there. See the syntax for the `newdata` argument in `predict.lm`. Your data frame supplied to the `newdata` argument must have the same names as the variables in the regression call.

Comment: See also the first two examples in the help on `predict.lm`

Comment: Notice in the first example in the help on `predict.lm` the new parameter is defined as new<-data.frame(x=-3,3,.5) where x is the regression variable in the model. How would I write it if I have 3 regression variables?

Comment: type `?data.frame` at the console to see how to create a data frame (then re-read my answer for details). Again, comments are not for extended discussion and *really* not for me to teach you the basics of how to use R; there are many tutorials for that.

Comment: Specifically see the first example in the help on data.frame; there's also lots of help online for how to create them, with many examples. If you have a new question about creating data frames, you can post it, of course (if it hasn't already been asked). A piece of advice: if in future you write your questions with a [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/330679), it makes it easier for answerers to give an explicit solution on the example data

Comment: I added some more specific detail to the answer.

Comment: @Ben thanks, but the intent was for that to be as it was -- that the entire quote after the heading was in backticks. However, I will leave it as is now.

Comment: oh, sorry.  Why? Seems harder to read to me ... I would opt for *either* block-quote *or* code formatting, not both at once?

Comment: I was trying to make it look more or less close to how it shows up when doing `help(predict.lm,help="text")` (i.e. getting it in the R session rather than in a browser, which is how I am used to reading it). I don't suppose that's a particularly compelling reason, which is why I didn't revert.

Comment: It was not the default response what I need but the interval="confidence" : predict.lm(res,newdata=data.frame(x1=4,x2=4,x3=2),interval="confidence")

Comment: @Isa Sorry,  I misunderstood your question -- where you said "type of interval calculation" I thought you were referring to the "type" argument. I see now you were referring to the interval argument in the comment above it. I had mentioned the need to specify the interval type before so I didn't think you could be referring to that (nevertheless, rereading now, clearly you did)

Comment: :) this one predict.lm(res,newdata=data.frame(x1=4,x2=4,x3=2),interval="confidence") instead of predict.lm(res,newdata=data.frame(x1=4,x2=4,x3=2))

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why I didn't see that comment before. Odd.